# How to show or hide element with checkbox input in Vue?

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am trying something like this:

```html
<b-form-checkbox
  id="currently_working"
  v-model="currentlyWorking"
  value="true"
  unchecked-value="false">
    <span class="fs--1">
      I am currently working here
    </span>
</b-form-checkbox>
</b-form-group>
<p v-if="currentlyWorking">currently working</p>
```

However, something is going wrong here because the paragraph tag isn't toggling based on  `currentWorking` state.
Here is the codesandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-night-jnhxz?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:43-361

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You need to for v-if boolean true and false but your component give you a string true and false. Good luck.

```js
 <b-form-checkbox
        id="currently_working"
        v-model="currentlyWorking"
        :value="true"
        :unchecked-value="false"
        ><span class="fs--1">
          I am currently working here
        </span></b-form-checkbox
      >
 </b-form-group>
```